# sharepoint calculated column to use internal ID instead of Display name

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have sharepoint list and I want to copy a value from one field to another.

For Example :

```
Display Name: WorkFlowID     ID: e2365-tg4wgf4-15rg44r-21314
Display Name: WorkFlowID     ID: WorkFlowID     (note: created by powershell)
```

Two fields has same display name but different internal ID. I try to copy the data from the one with GUID to one with WorkFlowID as internal ID.

calculated column formulas:

```
=[WorkFlowID]
```

Result is always is : 0

I think this happens because sharepoint list can't difference between columns. Is there any way to use the ID  instead of Display name ?

Comment: How did you manage to have to columns with identical display names? SharePoint doesnt even let me rename one column if a column with the second name already exists. But you should rename the source column and then hide it. The name doesnt matter in the view then.

Comment: Do both columns show in the formula builder in the UI?

Comment: @Serv using PowerShell we allow you to have multiple columns with same name but different IDs

Comment: @Truezplaya not both columns show in the formula builder . The source can not be changed

Comment: @KamalAL-Hinai can you try to create exactly the same column but with a different name and check it displays in the UI?

Comment: @Truezplaya I already test it , and it work

Comment: @KamalAL-Hinai sorted then?

Comment: @Truezplaya I already sorted it but I want to know if it's possible to use internal ID instead of display name